# Synonym for 'divided' or 'split'

Tags: word-request, synonyms

I'm looking for words that capture the meaning: being mentally divided or split. The feeling of "I'm not sure", insofar as one is heavily weighing the pros and cons of an idea on a intellectual or emotional level.

For example, you could write: "The question challenged his beliefs - suddenly he was divided." I feel however "divided" or "split" doesn't capture the implied meaning of moral compromise here.

I struggle to find a better word here, though I am sure it exists.

Comment: Maybe [conflicted](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/conflicted)?  It means "full of conflicting emotions or impulses".

Comment: This would work: *The question challenged his beliefs - suddenly he **hesitated***. *Hesitate* is not exactly a feeling, though.

Comment: You might like *undecided*  https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/undecided

Comment: I feel 'conflicted' captures the idea best, but thank you as well for all the other suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

[Thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/divided) mentions

> **Main Entry:** forked
>   **Part of Speech:** adjective
>   **Definition:** going separate ways
>   **Synonyms:** angled, bifid, bifurcate, bifurcated, branched, branching, dichotomous, dichotomic, divaricate, divided, furcate, furcated, pronged, split, tined, tridented, zigzag
>   **Antonyms:** joined, unbranched

When talking about the mind being split you could use [bifurcated](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/bifurcated) or [dichotomic](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/dichotomic) (Divided into two branches or forks)

Another expression you could use is

> He was **in two minds**

Answer (score 0):

The word for *'...The feeling of "I'm not sure", insofar as one is heavily weighing the pros and cons of an idea on a intellectual or emotional level.'* is '[dilemma](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dilemma)'. I have also seen the 'types' of dilemma which may include 'mental' or 'ethical'.

If the question challenges your belief, you could be in a *dilemma* whether or not to keep the 'belief' anymore.

Others may come up with more words.

Comment: I've never heard anyone use the phrase "in dilemma".  Maybe "in **a** dilemma", but *dilemma* really refers to the situation, not the feeling.

Comment: @stangdon The OP seems to talk about the 'feeling' according to the 'situation' only as he says weighing pros and cons and the *uncertainty* based on it!